# What exactly rq->cfs.load value represent in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux kernel. I was reading about CFS scheduler of Linux from here

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt

I came across few lines

**The total number of running tasks in the runqueue is accounted through the
rq->cfs.load value, which is the sum of the weights of the tasks queued on the
runqueue.**

Now, if rq->cfs.load tells about total number of runnable processes then it should be a number like :
3  -> 3 processes are runnable
5 -> 5 processes are runnable

But actual value of rq->cfs.load is sum of weight of processes.

My questions are :

1. How can weighted sum tell about the number of runnable processes?
2. What we mean by weight of processes here ?

Answer (score 0):

I am still a beginner in Linux. But from what I understand , it means

> **1.I think you got a bit confused:** Whenever the number of process increase(its a change) , some scheduling parameters needs to be
>   changed. The scheduling class functions rather than counting the
>   number of process, it uses it's load value to calculate its
>   parameters. So the change(i.e. increase in the number of processes) is
>   accounted ( i.e. taken into consideration) to calculate the load value
>   through cfs_rq->load variable. And we do this updation of cfs_rq->load
>   by summing the weight of the process.

---

> **2. weight of process:**  Weight of process is calculated through its dynamic priority. How is Dynamic Prority calculated? Dynamic Priority calculation :
>   Static priority + "scheduling class of the process to be
>   scheduled"(i.e. real-time vs Normal) are used to calculate Dynamic
>   priority. The calculation is not simple addition. Read this [Link from
>   UTLK](http://books.google.com/books?id=h0lltXyJ8aIC&pg=PT281&lpg=PT281&dq=default%20static%20priority%20linux&source=bl&ots=gN8oLV7fGS&sig=wJtiz-wqnZ4ppDFj4BAD974wjRM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7QYRU_iHJNHwoATYqIGoCg&ved=0CH0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=default%20static%20priority%20linux&f=false) . Read some link for static priorities as well.